# multiload-ng not installing

Tags: xfce

I am trying to install `multiload-ng`from the webupd8 ppa according to  [this guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/alternative-system-monitor-applet-for.html) on Ubuntu 18.04 in the XFCE desktop. I run the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfce4-multiload-ng-plugin
```

as copied from the guide.  However, I get the response

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xfce4-multiload-ng-plugin
```

How should I proceed to install `multiload-ng`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While following any guide with PPAs you should determine existence of the packages for your release.

The [`ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+index?field.series_filter=&batch=75&direction=backwards&memo=600&start=525) has `xfce4-multiload-ng-plugin` package for supported [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://pkgs.org/download/multiload-ng), but not for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

You should consider other methods to use. For example you may want to download Xenial version manually and then install it the system:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/m/multiload-ng/multiload-ng-common_1.5.2-1~webupd8~xenial0_all.deb
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/m/multiload-ng/xfce4-multiload-ng-plugin_1.5.2-1~webupd8~xenial0_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*multiload-ng*.deb
```

It will work this way:

[image: Multiload NG 1.5.2 from Xenial on Bionic]

Comment: Thank you, this did it.  I would welcome any recommendations about where I can read more about how to do this sort of thing on my own.  As in, how can I tell whether a package is supported for an older version of Ubuntu only?

Comment: You can try to [contact PPA owner](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+contactuser) and request package building for new versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Also works for the same PPA repository, under XFCE 4.18 (Xubuntu 22.04), with multiload-ng - 1.5.2+git20210103-1~webupd8~focal2 these focal binaries.